# Same host IP number at red5phone client

Tags: connection, client, red5

I implemented red5phone with asterisk as external sip proxy. I tried to connect with 2 clients and there's definitely a different IP. When I saw at asterisk by using the `sip show peers` cli command, it displayed like this :

```
Name/username              Host            Dyn Nat ACL Port     Status    
1001/1001                  10.151.32.26     D   N      38841    OK (173 ms)
1000/1000                  10.151.32.26    D          5060     OK (17 ms)
```

The host IP is the same, although it's a different client.

Can somebody explain this? Is it an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's your proxy ip address and that's fine because each user is identified by port number which is different

Comment: emmm, okay dawid, I see. So, I can continue to build app. thanks for answer.

Comment: dawid, I want to ask something. Why it's just use port number for identification. If I use other softphone, like Xlite, it's use ip address. Do you know the reason?

Comment: hi, when you register softphones Like Xlite you only provide server's ip address and once the server receives your request it will analyze the source ip and port number and use this info to contact the user in the future ,this is why on asterisk you see:
001/1001 10.151.32.26 D N 38841 OK (173 ms) 1000/1000 10.151.32.26 D 5060 OK (17 ms)

so when you will try to call user 1001 asterisk will send a request trying to contact the user @ ip 10.151.32.26 and port 38841, when you will try to call user 1000 it will send a request to the same ip but port 5060.

Comment: I get an answer from the developer. It's because the SIP client is at Red5 Server so it use same ip address but using port number as identification. thanks Dawid, nice analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Is that IP address the IP address of the red5 server? Perhaps your red5 server is not passing the client IP addresses but its own to Asterisk?

Comment: yes, it's IP address of red5 server. I don't know about passing client IP addresses, but I sure that this from different ip address client.